# What does using namespace std; do?

Tags: c++

What is the matter with this C++ code?

I get an error message saying: that there should be a `;` before `z`, which is not correct. The only part that I don't understand is the purpose line 2 serves.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int subtraction(int a, int b)
{
    int r;
    r=a-b;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int z;
    z = subtraction (5,9);
    cout z;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not how `cout` is used.

Comment: Related [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Instead of `int r; r=a-b;` use initialization: `int r=a-b;`. Same for `z`.

Comment: Just use `cout << z;` and you will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

`using namespace std;` means you can write `cout` later on rather than `std::cout`. It saves typing at the expense of gross *namespace pollution*.

Your compile error can be fixed by writing `cout << z;`

Also, do return a value from `main`.

Comment: If there's no explicit `return` in the `main` function, the compiler will add a `return 0` at the end.

Comment: Indeed. @JoachimPileborg is referring to C++ Standard, chapter 3.6.1 paragraph 5. Yup, you can do this for `main()`, but not any other function.

Comment: I was under the impression that calling the iostream library allowed for the use of `cout`, not `namespace std;`. If `namespace std;` is what allows for `cout`, then what does the iostream library call?

Comment: That's a good observation@KadenHardy: The non-standard `#include <iostream.h>` gives you `cout`, but you should use the standard `#include <iostream>`, where you *need* to use `std::cout`.

Answer (score 2):

To begin to explain what this does, it is important for you to understand what namespaces do. Namespaces are logical units of code divided up, you are able to create your own namespace or use other namespaces. The benefit of using namespaces is to have your program logically divide up your code with like functions. This is very similar to classes, but you do not need initiation of the namespaces like classes do. IN Java this would be similar to packages. To use a function within a namespace you need to use the namespace identifier followed by the function you are calling. This will call the correct function in the namespace scope you are wanting to use. An example of creating a namespace is the following:

```
namespace connection 
{
 int create_connection();
 int close_connection();
 //ect.......
}
```

Then later in the code when you want to call create_connection you need to do it the following way:

```
connection::create_connection();
```

As for your answer you are able to prevent from having to type the namespace identifier in this case connection, or in your case std. You are able to introduce an entire namespace into a section of code by using a using-directive. This will allow you to call the functions that are in that namespace without needing to use the namespace followed with the scope indicator" :: ".

The following syntax to do this is as follows:

```
using namespace connection:
```

or in your case

```
using namespace std;
```

So by doing this with std you will be granting that access to std namespace which includes C++ I/O objects cout and cin to use freely without having to use the namespace and scope operator first. Though a better practice is to limit the scope to the namespace members you want to actually use. On large programs this will be cleaner why of coding as well as avoid several problems. To introduce only specific members of a namespace, such as only introducing the std::cin and std::cout, you do the following:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
```

Comment: A great answer, sadly too late for the initial upvote flurry. But here's a plus one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> What does using namespace `std;` do?

**It tells the compiler which class/namespace to look in for an identifier.** You either use `using namespace std;` in the beginning of the file or have to place it in front of each function that belongs to it.

> What is the matter with this C++ code?

The syntax to use `std::cout` is:

```
std::cout << source;
```

variable `source` is inserted with the help of `operator <<` in the `std::cout` stream which prints it to the standard output, i.e. computer monitor.

---

<sup>`std` *"labels"* a function member of the Standard Library. This is a technique used (among other reasons) to resolve (using the resolution operator `::`) members that belong to the Standard Library from (possible) name conflicts with functions with similar(same) names and to reduce a scope of a search. `std` is called a namespace, so `using namespace std;` is a bit self explanatory.</sup>