# What actually using namespace std is

Tags: c++

In GCC compiler we have to use using namespace std; if its not added program compiles but input output dont work. While in compiler like turbo c++ input output finely wirk without use of using namespace std; What actually that using namespace std is

Comment: In a single search you can learn std in google. try it in google.

Comment: [What does using namespace std; do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905981/what-does-using-namespace-std-do) [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)